# Android aynctask json

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using this piece of code to download json data from Reddit. The code works in a test java project I created but does not when I use it on my android device. On the android device it will only download a fraction of the json data. I cannot figure out why. Thank you for any help.

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    String c;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) urls[0].getContent()));
            while((c = in.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(c);
            }
            in.close();
            json = new JSONObject(str.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting any error? How did you know its a fraction of data?

Comment: @jaga I know it is a fraction of the data because I type into my browser http://www.reddit.com/.json and verify it against what I print out on the eclipse console from my phone.

Comment: eclipse console might display only a part of json if the string is long. Try parsing the json and check if you have the data.

Comment: @H.T. like jaga said, console might not show the whole string. Better parse the json and get the URLs count and check if its same as in browser.

Comment: @jaga Thank you I figured it out. Eclipse wasn't showing everything and I made a mistake parsing it.

Comment: Do upvote or accept any answer which helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
public resultModel getJSONfromReddit() {

        resultModel result = new resultModel();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://www.reddit.com/.json");

        try {
            response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
            String JSONString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),
                    "UTF-8");
            JSONObject json = null;
            json = new JSONObject(JSONString);
            Log.i(TAG, JSONString); //this is the whole response but it'll be cutted if you only print it in the eclipse logcat

            //PARSE YOUR JSON HERE

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Maybe your JSON is cutted in the eclipse console you can tried to get parse the JSON and print the last data to verify it, I hope my answer is clear enough but if you want to ask some question about my answer like how to parse JSON (I assume you know how to do this) feel free to ask in the comment :)

Comment: @NAYOSE Thank you but I figured out the problem.